# Simplifying the boolean expression: (A ∧ ¬C) ∨ (B ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ B)

Tags: boolean-logic

Suppose I have the following logical expression: (A ∧ ¬C) ∨ (B ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ B)

Why does this simplify to (A ∧ ¬C) ∨ (B ∧ C)?

The truth tables are the same but I cannot get to the second expression with my current knowledge of the laws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to reduce `AC' + BC + AB` to `AC' + BC`:

```hs
  AC' + BC + AB
= AC' + BC + AB (C + C')   -- C + C' = 1
= AC' + BC + ABC + ABC'    -- distribute
= AC' + ABC' + BC + ABC    -- rearrange
= AC' (1 + B) + BC (1 + A) -- factorize
= AC' + BC                 -- 1 + X = 1
```

Shoutout to [jq170727](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8379597/jq170727) for helping me arrive at the solution.

---

The truth table for `AC' + BC + AB` is:

```
C A B | Y
------+---
0 0 0 | 0
0 0 1 | 0
0 1 0 | 1
0 1 1 | 1
1 0 0 | 0
1 0 1 | 1
1 1 0 | 0
1 1 1 | 1
```

Hence, the Karnaugh map for it is:

```
   | A'B'| A'B | A B | A B'
---+-----+-----+-----+-----
 C'|  0  |  0  | (1  |  1)
 C |  0  | [1  |  1] |  0
```

As you can see, there are only two group which I've clearly marked with parentheses and square brackets respectively. Note that we **do not** group the elements of the `A B` column together because all its elements are already in groups. Thus, the result is `AC' + BC`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - super helpful. BTW, I got the first expression through a Karnaugh Map on Mux (if sel = 0, then output a, else output b). Do you know why the Karnaugh Map did not produce the more simplified expression? Or do Karnaugh Maps not produce the absolutely most simplified expression?

Comment: Karnaugh maps always produce the simplest expression. If you didn't get the simplest expression then you're not grouping the elements properly.

Comment: Are you sure? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32462/do-karnaugh-maps-yield-the-simplest-solution-possible

Comment: I'll try again. I have three adjacent pairs in the Karnaugh Map, and that means it's a three term expression.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Note however that Karnaugh maps produce the simplest expression in [canonical normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form). For example, `A ⊻ B` (i.e. `A` xor `B`) has the canonical representation `(¬A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B)`. It's the simplest sum of products but not the simplest non-canonical expression.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how the Karnaugh map for `(A ∧ ¬C) ∨ (B ∧ C) ∨ (A ∧ B)` produces the simpler expression `(A ∧ ¬C) ∨ (B ∧ C)`.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't downvote anything, are you sure it was me?

Comment: I understand now, I didn't know we were not supposed to group the elements in the same column. I will find out more information about that. Thanks.